# inject dependencies injection with parameters

Tags: .net, dependency-injection

I'm using ASP .net 6 to create web api.
My project structure looks like this:

in controller

```cs
puclic AccountController(IAccountService service) { }
```

in service

```cs
public AccountService(DatabaseContext db) { }
```

in DatabaseContext

```cs
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext(string connectionString) : base() { }
}
```

in `Startup.cs`

```cs
// ...
services.AddTransient<IAccountService, AccountService>();
services.AddSingleton<AccountController, AccountController>();
var connectionString = "we can get connection string here";
services.AddTransient(_ => new DatabaseContext(connectionString));
```

my problem is when I build, everything is ok, but when I run the code, it throws this execption

> Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: API.Common.DatabaseContext Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: API.Common.DatabaseContext': Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'API.Common.DatabaseContext'.)
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: API.Common.DatabaseContext Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: API.Common.DatabaseContext': Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'API.Common.DatabaseContext'.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'API.Common.DatabaseContext'.

if the `DatabaseContext` constructor is a parameterless constructor, everything is ok. but when I pass parameter to this class, the above exception was thrown.
How can I fix this issue with parameter in DatabaseContext constructor

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to pass a connection string to an EF Core DbContext, please see [the EF Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#dbcontext-in-dependency-injection-for-aspnet-core):

```cs
services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => 
  options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

However, if you want to configure the connection string in `OnConfiguring()`, you could pass in another object that has the connection string:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>();
services.AddSingleton(new DatabaseOptions {
    ConnectionString = "my connection string";
});
```

```cs
public class DatabaseOptions
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}

public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext(DatabaseOptions options) { 
        // We can read options.ConnectionString here
    }
}
```

You may also want to look at the [options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-8.0).

Comment: I just want to send connection string in database context class to provide connection string for writing test purpose. and there're also some typo in my code in question. I've just edited it. the `services.AddDbContext` I just added to `Startup` class and also add it in `OnConfiguring` function in `DatabaseContext` class

Comment: The issue is not with the code posted in your question. The issue is that `AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>()` will not work when the constructor of `DatabaseContext` has a string. In other words, you simply cannot put a string in the constructor for the DatabaseContext. However, you could put other parameters, like `DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options` - or you could pass the connection string into a public property of the class after construction.

Comment: The public connection string property is my current solution in this case when I cannot pass parameter to `DatabaseContext` class. But it's not my prefered / exprected solution. I just want to use parameter in constructor instead of using public connection string property

Comment: You can do this by removing `services.AddTransient()` for you `DatabaseContext`, and then creating an "options" object that contains your connection string. Updated my answer with the suggestion.

Comment: your idea with sending object containning connection string I've tried but it has no change. still throws same exception